# Append element of two nested lists with separate order in R

Tags: r

I try to append the element `github` from the `listA` to `listB` based on the element `id`. How can I achieve this ?

```
G1 <- list(id = "aaa", github = "www.github.aaa")
G2 <- list(id = "bbb", github = "www.github.bbb")

R1 <- list(id = "aaa", reddit = "www.reddit.aaa")
R2 <- list(id = "bbb", reddit = "www.reddit.bbb")

listA <- list(G1, G2)
listB <- list(R2, R1)
```

With :

```
> listB
[[1]]
[[1]]$id
[1] "bbb"

[[1]]$reddit
[1] "www.reddit.bbb"


[[2]]
[[2]]$id
[1] "aaa"

[[2]]$reddit
[1] "www.reddit.aaa"
```

What I'm trying to do is :

```
> listB
[[1]]
[[1]]$id
[1] "bbb"

[[1]]$reddit
[1] "www.reddit.bbb"

[[1]]$github
[1] "www.github.bbb"


[[2]]
[[2]]$id
[1] "aaa"

[[2]]$reddit
[1] "www.reddit.aaa"

[[1]]$github
[1] "www.github.aaa"
```

I try with `mapply` but it doesn't give me the expected result. Instead it cross the two list:

```
> mapply(c, listA, listB, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
[[1]]
[[1]]$id
[1] "aaa"

[[1]]$github
[1] "www.github.aaa"

[[1]]$id
[1] "bbb"

[[1]]$reddit
[1] "www.reddit.bbb"


[[2]]
[[2]]$id
[1] "bbb"

[[2]]$github
[1] "www.github.bbb"

[[2]]$id
[1] "aaa"

[[2]]$reddit
[1] "www.reddit.aaa"
```

Thank you

Comment: Sorry, i just added a reproducible example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to convert them to data.frames and perform a `merge`:

```
merge(do.call(rbind, lapply(listA, data.frame, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)),
      do.call(rbind, lapply(listB, data.frame, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)), by="id")
```

this returns

```
   id         github         reddit
1 aaa www.github.aaa www.reddit.aaa
2 bbb www.github.bbb www.reddit.bbb
```

Comment: And OP and future readers, in R, data.frames are **lists** of equal-length atomic vectors.